# setstate isn't setting value to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm setting my state after calculating it in mouseup and mouse leave event but it's not updating it how to solve in mouseup and mouse leave

`Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within render). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.`

```
onMouseMove = (e) => {
        if (!this.isDown) {
            return;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        var x = e.pageX - this.slider.current.offsetLeft;
        var walk = x - this.startX;
        this.startX = x;
        var z = walk;
        var finalValue = this.state.left + (z / 3);
        finalValue = Math.floor(finalValue * 100) / 100;
        this.setState({ left: finalValue }, () => { });
        this.setState({ percent: false })
    }

onMouseLeave = () => {
        this.isDown = false;
        var left = this.state.left;
        for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            this.el = 306*[i]
            console.log(this.el);

            if (left<=this.el) {
             this.setState({left:this.el},()=>{})
            //  return
            }
            console.log(this.state.left);

        }
    }
    onMouseUp = () => {
        this.isDown = false;
        this.slider.current.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        var left = this.state.left;
        for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            this.el = 306*[i]
            console.log(this.el);

            if (left<=this.el) {
             this.setState({left:this.el},()=>{})
            //  return
            }
            console.log(this.state.left);

        }

    }



 render() {
            return (
                    <div className="slider-wrapper" >
                        <div onMouseDown={this.onMouseDown}
 style={this.state.percent ? this.goLeftPercent() : this.mouseMove()}
```

onMouseUp={this.onMouseUp} onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave}
     onMouseMove={this.onMouseMove} ref={this.slider} className="slider-container">  
                )
            }

Comment: Share the full code to understand better.

Comment: How are you calling this function?

Comment: it wont let me post

Comment: im calling those function on mouseup and mouseleave events

Comment: Could you share your render method, like that we will be able to help better.

Comment: If sounds like in your JSX, you're calling the function instead of referencing it. As in, instead of `={this.onMouseUp()}` you need to use `={this.onMouseUp}` (or even better: `={e => this.onMouseUp(e)}` which will bind `this`.)

Comment: im using arrow function i still need to bind it?

Comment: here's how im calling it <div onMouseUp={this.onMouseUp} onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave}></div>

Comment: You don't need to bind it you use arrow functions. Can you share the code of this.mouseMove()?

Comment: i added the mouse move method

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you can try the below changes.

**Constructor**

```
constructor() {
        super();

this.onMouseLeave = this.onMouseLeave.bind(this);
this.onMouseUp = this.onMouseUp.bind(this);

}
```

**Render()**

```
<li onMouseUp={this.onMouseUp} onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave} >
```

Comment: im using arrow function i still need to bind it?

Comment: Post the render method. That will give clear picture to help you

Comment: i posted my render method